# What is UIATargetHasGoneAWOLException while operating iphone with UIAutomation through Instruments.

Tags: xcode, instruments, ui-automation, ios-ui-automation

I am using UIAutomation, through Instruments from Xcode, to do something on iPhone, and got a weird exception: 
      UIATargetHasGoneAWOLException.

Anybody know what does this exception mean?

Answer (score 5):

I've found that this occurs when certain unknown conditions exist AND an iPhone is connected to the computer. Disconnecting the iPhone will solve the problem.

Unfortunately, I don't know what the "certain unknown conditions" are, because a connected iPhone device doesn't automatically result in this exception. But I do see that disconnecting the iPhone is sufficient to prevent it.

Comment: I agree. Here's an Open Radar that covers this: http://openradar.appspot.com/11168782

Answer (score 0):

I found **[this article](http://psellos.com/2012/11/2012.11.iossim-apps-awol.html)** that gives a great explanation for `UIATargetHasGoneAWOLException`, and his solution worked for me.

Basically, the generated `Info.plist` file inside your `.app` is missing some attributes. I was able to add the following to my `Info.plist` and it worked as expected:

```
    <key>CFBundleSupportedPlatforms</key>
    <array>
            <string>iPhoneSimulator</string>
    </array>
    <key>DTPlatformName</key>
    <string>iphonesimulator</string>
    <key>DTSDKName</key>
    <string>iphonesimulator6.0</string>
    <key>UIDeviceFamily</key>
    <array>
            <integer>1</integer>
    </array>
```

Btw, Xcode by default builds your `.app` binary in `~/Library/Application Support/iPhone Simulator/6.1/Applications/...`, where `...` is some random ID string that Xcode generates. Once you locate the right Application directory, right click on your `.app` file and `Show Package Contents`. In there, you'll find the `Info.plist` file where you can add the above code.