# Exception when launch application on device with instruments command of xcode5

Tags: ios7

My xcode is upgraded to 5.0, when I use instruments command to launch app as follow:
instruments -w 1ca20d9f0a864fe487218935aa76ec055b2609b5 -t /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Applications/Instruments.app/Contents/PlugIns/AutomationInstrument.bundle/Contents/Resources/Automation.tracetemplate example.app

Then an error occured:
Automation Instrument ran into an exception while trying to run the script.  UIANoScriptToRun
Fail: An error occurred while trying to run the script.

The command works prefectly with xcode4.6.3, but get exception on xcode5.0(command tool is also installed).

How to resolve this issue?Many thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Could be that Xcode is running the Run Scripts with limited rights?

Check this if you can:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/14161519/1648154